# VBA powerpoint. set a shape as a variable

Tags: vba, object, shapes

I have a very simple question, I have searched how to select a powerpoint shape, and the code that I've found as follows.

```
Presentation.Slide(1).Shape(1)
```

But when I do this

```
Dim a As Shape
Set a=Presentation.Slide(1).Shape(1)
```

I get a type mismatch. What object class does the presentation.slide().shape() command returns?. The MSDN site says its a shape object (" read only ", which I dont know what that means)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/slide-shapes-property-powerpoint.

So why does the code above has a mismatch error.

Also, how can I know which class of object a line of code would return. For example, I want to write something like this in a console, to get back the class of the object it produces

```
Class(Presentantion.Slide(1).Shape(1))
```

(If there is a console)

Answer (score 0):

Some typos in your posted code

```
typename(activepresentation.slides(1).shapes(1))
```

will give you what you want i think.